# Get sqlalchemy table Model and Field objects from strings?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy

Very simple trying to run a query in Python 3 sqlalchemy to delete some records given string names of table and field to query against.

1. How do you get the table object from a string?
2. Given 1. how do you run a query via ORM with just a string of the field name?

I would assume all **ORM**'s have an internal array or method like `get` with the name.

```py
json_config = [
    {"table": "tableA",
     "field": "modified_on"
     "expires": 30},
    {"table": "tableB",
     "field": "event_on"
     "expires": 30}
]

for table_conf_item in self.json_config:
    table_name = table_conf_item["table"]
    field_name = table_conf_item["field"]
    expire_after = table_conf_item["expires"]
    table_obj = self.orm_session.TABLES[table_name]
    field_obj = self.orm_session.TABLES[table_name].FIELDS[field_name]
    result = self.orm_session.delete(table_obj).where(field_obj < expire_after)
    self.orm_session.commit()
    print(f"{table_name}: removed {result.row_count} objects")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the table's name, you can use [reflection](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/reflection.html#reflecting-database-objects) to get a [Table](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Table) object.  Using SQLAlchemy's core layer, this is reasonably straightforward:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa

engine = sa.create_engine(...)

tbl = sa.Table(name_of_table, metadata, autoload_with=engine)
```

If you want to work with multiple tables, it may be more efficient to store them a Metadata instance for later access:

```
metadata = sa.MetaData()
metadata.reflect(engine, only=list_of_table_names)
tbl = metadata.tables[name_of_table]
```

Once you have a `Table` object you can reference columns by name like this: `tbl.c[name_of_field]`.

Full example:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa

# Setup
engine = sa.create_engine('sqlite://', echo=True, future=True)

tbl = sa.Table(
    't',
    sa.MetaData(),
    sa.Column('id', sa.Integer, primary_key=True),
    sa.Column('foo', sa.Integer),
)

tbl.create(engine)

with engine.begin() as conn:
    vals = [42, 43, 42, 43, 56, 87, 89]
    conn.execute(tbl.insert(), [{'foo': v} for v in vals])

del tbl

# Reflect the table.
metadata = sa.MetaData()
metadata.reflect(engine, only=['t'])
tbl = metadata.tables['t']

# Define some statements.
q1 = sa.select(tbl).where(tbl.c['foo'] == 42)
q2 = sa.select(tbl.c['id'], tbl.c['foo']).where(tbl.c['foo'] == 43)
q3 = sa.delete(tbl).where(tbl.c['foo'] != 42)

# Execute the statements.
with engine.connect() as conn:
    rows = conn.execute(q1)
    for row in rows:
        print(row)
    print()
    rows = conn.execute(q2)
    for row in rows:
        print(row)
    print()

with engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.execute(q3)


with engine.connect() as conn:
    rows = conn.execute(q1)
    for row in rows:
        print(row)
    print()
```

Doing the same through the ORM layer is more complicated, as table and column names must be mapped to ORM entity classes (models) and their attributes. This replicates the previous example for a simple mapping (it assumes the same initial data as above).

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy import orm

Base = orm.declarative_base()


class Thing(Base):
    __tablename__ = 't'

    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    thing_foo = sa.Column('foo', sa.Integer)


engine = sa.create_engine(...)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
Session = orm.sessionmaker(engine, future=True)

tablename = 't'
columnname = 'foo'

with Session.begin() as s:
    # Get the mappers for the Base class.
    mappers = Base.registry.mappers
    # Get the mapper for our table.
    mapper = next(m for m in mappers if m.entity.__tablename__ == tablename)
    # Get the entity class (Thing).
    entity = mapper.entity
    # Get the column from the Table.
    table_column = mapper.selectable.c[columnname]
    # Get the mapper property that corresponds to the column
    # (the entity attribute may have a different name to the 
    # column in the database).
    mapper_property = mapper.get_property_by_column(table_column)
    # Get the queryable entity attribute (Thing.thing_foo).
    attr = mapper.all_orm_descriptors[mapper_property.key]
    q = sa.select(entity).where(attr != 42)
    entities = s.scalars(q)
    for entity in entities:
        s.delete(entity)

with Session() as s:
    for thing in s.scalars(sa.select(Thing)):
        print(thing.id, thing.thing_foo)
```

Comment: Why do all these SQL alchemy examples create and populate tables? I would assume >50% of work is done with pre-existing tables. I don't need to create tables or create schema, its already there. All I want to do is delete records via a config file that has 3 items: table name, field name, and expiration date. So I would assume an ORM that's nearing version 2.0 has a way to address EXISTING tables metadata.

Comment: @RonaldoNascimento - Examples are often intended to be self-contained — similar to a [mcve] — so it is clear exactly what the example code is doing. They are provided to instruct, not to give you code that you can copy/paste into your project. If you want that then hire a consultant.

Comment: @RonaldoNascimento re: "a way to address EXISTING tables metadata" - See `tbl = sa.Table('t', sa.MetaData(), autoload_with=engine)` above.

Comment: @RonaldoNascimento Do the example statements not show you how to achieve your goal?

Comment: As with all python examples, no imports are shown, in fact if you search for `Table` in the SQLalchemy docs, all the examples fail to show what imports are needed.

Comment: They appear to provide the goal of what I want to do, I can get a proper Model object of the table, but when I try to run the `result = orm.delete(tbl).where(tbl.c['filename']< 30)` I get an error: UnmappedInstanceError: Table is not mapped

Comment: The error means you are working with an ORM session but using lower level core constructs (Tables and the columns).  I've added an example of how to do the deletion if you need to use the ORM layer.  If you don't need it using Tables and engines will be easier.  I've also shown how you can reflect multiple tables into a single metadata instance, which provides an object that you can use to look up tables by name.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is where my confusion lies and I need to revisit learning and reading the SQLalchemy docs. I was frustrated trying to fix a bug before the weekend break, I apologize. I will try this is out.